# EditText has focus when Activity starts, but soft keyboard is not shown

Tags: android, android-edittext

as mentioned above, the keyboard does not show up, although the EditText is focused (orange border) and the cursor is blinking.
When I click into text field, it opens up, however I want it to be open right when the activity starts.

I tried setting `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible"` in the activity, I tried `showSoftInput(yourTextBox, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);` and also `requestFocus()`.
But no success...

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPasswd);

((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE))
    .showSoftInput(myEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED);
```

Are you testing on emulator? If you do, you should know that keyboard doesn't pop up on emulator :), but it does on a real device

Good luck,
Arkde

Answer (score 1):

Another way to show the keyboard when the Activity is created is to add this code in your `AndroidManifest` file  for the activity which you want to show the keyboard on starts :

```
<activity android:name=".UserLogin" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"/>
```